# A certain step in a proof of König's theorem from Hrbacek-Jech "Introduction to Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of König's theorem in set theory using Hrbacek's and Jech's book "Introduction to Set Theory".

In the end, the proof сomes down to a certain result or lemma, which I'm having a trouble with understanding.

> Let $(Y_i)_{i \in I}$ be indexed family. Then there can be no indexed family $(Z_i)_{i \in I}$ so that
>
> - $(\forall i,j \in I)(i \neq j \Longrightarrow Z_i\cap Z_j = \varnothing),$
> - $(\forall i \in I)(|Z_i| < |Y_i|),$
> - $\bigcup_{i \in I} Z_i = \prod_{i \in I} Y_i$.

Hrbacek and Jech proceed the following way. They defined a new family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ so that $A_i$ is the subset of $Y_i$ of all elements $y$ for which there is a function $f\colon I\to\bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i$ in $Z_i$ so that $y = f(i)$. Then they claim that for any $i \in I$, $A_i \subsetneq Y_i$ since $|A_i| \leq |Z_i| < |Y_i|$. This is where is stumble: I don't understand why we have $|A_i| \leq |Z_i|$ for each $i \in I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $y\in A_i,$ by definition, there is a function $f\in Z_i$ such that $y=f(i);$ choose such an $f$ and call it $f_y.$ (Axiom of choice used here.) The inequality $|A_i|\le|Z_i|$ follows from the fact that $y\mapsto f_y$ is an injective map from $A_i$ to $Z_i.$ Namely, if $y,z\in A_i$ and $f_y=f_z,$ then $y=f_y(i)=f_z(i)=z.$

Answer (score 1):

So, in a formula: $A_i=\{y\in Y_i:(\exists f\in Z_i)(y=f(i))\}$, or a bit shorter: $A_i=\{f(i): f\in Z_i\}$. The last formulation shows that $A_i$ is the image of $Z_i$ under the map $f\mapsto f(i)$. In general: if $g:P\to Q$ is any map then $|g[P]|\le|P|$ (this uses a bit of AC).

Comment: But how do we know that $A_i$ if the image of $Z_i$ under this map and not simply a set containing the image. That is, how to we know that the map $f\mapsto f(i)$ is surjective?

Comment: By the very definition of $A_i$ as <b>the</b> set of all elements of the form $f(i)$ for some $f\in Z_i$.